# Show render information in render image

Tags: rendering

I saw this in a tutorial but i can't find it anymore.
I want to save my render information like the amount samples and time IN the rendered image. but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Render Settings** -> **Metadata** -> Check what you want to "Stamp" on the image and uncheck what you don't want,

[image]

Comment: appreciate ya!!

Comment: Always happy to help :)